# how can i adding custom path for saving the zip_file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I am creating a zip file using the `zipfile` module. It works like a charm. but that's file, saved in the executed script place.
my script path is a:
[b]c:/User/Administrator/[/b]script.py
and the `zipfile` saved in:
[b]c:/User/Administrator/[/b]backup.zip

but I want, [b]creating a `zipfile`, in another path[/b], like this:
[b]d:/backups/[/b]backup.zip

my code like this:

```py
import zipfile

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile("backup.zip", 'w')
with zip_file:
    for file in filePaths:
        zip_file.write(file)
```

my question is a how can I adding custom path for saving the `zip_file`. because I have not an enough space in C:

tnx a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the path you want to `ZipFile` function.
When you give only the name of the `file`, it will save the `file` in the current directory which the program is running.
Do this instead:

```py
import zipfile
# For example you want to save it in drive 'D'
path = "D:\\PathToYourDir\\backup.zip"
zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(path, 'w')
with zip_file:
    for file in filePaths:
        zip_file.write(file)
```